# What is the default connection limit of .Net remoting http channel?

Tags: .net, asp.net, remoting

When using .net remoting, does the server limit incoming client remoting calls?

I find a particular remoting call (during ASP.NET page rendering) to take from 200ms to 1500ms. While the underlying data call is only 50ms.  Factoring in remoting overhead of 150ms per call, the only difference between the two cases is that the latter scenario has about a dozen more parallel remoting calls in progress.  So my guess is that when too many remoting calls are happening, some will get queued up?  I also doubt system resource is the cause of the delay because it is not nearly saturated.

Searching MSDN, I find the below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973907.aspx

> clientConnectionLimit: specifies how
>   many connections can be simultaneously
>   opened to a given server. The default
>   is 2. This is exactly the same as the
>   connection limit on ServicePoint in
>   the net classes.

That seems awfully low to me and if were the case, my app's performance would have been much worse.

Can someone confirm if there is indeed a connection limit or some other throttling in .net remoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit will change this limit, but it must be called prior to the instantiation of the ServicePoint.  ServicePoint created prior to the change will not be affected.

And I think the default for http 1.1 is 10, not 2.